# Is there a way to add CSS to a title element in a SVG file?

Tags: css, svg

I am working on an SVG file that has a number of `<path>` tags. I also have a `<title>` tag for each of these `<path>` tags. I have text inside the `<title>` tag such that when I hover over the `<path>` element, it displays the text. However, the text is the default format, bland text with an ugly looking border box etc.

Is there a way where I can use CSS to modify the `<title>` tag so that it can look better?

This is what I have thus far:

```
 <title>
      Title Tag!!!
 </title>
 <path d="M696.393,-204.269C703.418,-219.592 708.202,-238.899 697,-252 671.205,-282.169 562.896,-290.806 492.399,-293.194" fill="none" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"></path>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **browser element** and you cannot style it.

If that helps you could make custom tooltip by yourself, look for example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).
Making custom tooltip will probably require some amendments in your code though.